# Angular material mat-menu not displayed with start action in other component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-7

In my App componnent I displayed a menu in the top screen using

```
 <mat-tab-group >
            <!-- Global Configuration menu -->
            <mat-tab>
                <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                    <a [matMenuTriggerFor]="Menu" class="cloneIcon">
                        Configuration Global
                    </a>
                </ng-template>

                <mat-menu #Menu="matMenu">
                        <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/admin/global" routerLinkActive="active" >
                                <mat-icon>build</mat-icon>
                                <span>Add Global Configuration</span>
                         </button>
                         <button mat-menu-item >
                                <mat-icon>calendar_today</mat-icon>
                                <span>Manage Planning</span>
                         </button>
                         <button mat-menu-item>
                                <mat-icon>notification_important</mat-icon>
                                <span> Manage Holidays & WE</span>
                         </button>
                </mat-menu>
            </mat-tab>
```

Then display the pages from other components using routing

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My menu is working correctly the problem when I call a function in other component it's not displayed more and there's no error in console

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking, and what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm using a SPA and the menu in the parent component it display correctly but when i call an action on other component it's not displayed

Comment: Can you please share code of function which you are mentioning ?